# Show that $k (X)/k$ is not algebraic.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

How do I argue that $k (X)/k$ is not an algebraic extension? I think since $X$ is indeterminant there exists no non-zero polynomial in $k [X]$ having $X$ as a root.Hence $X$ is transcendental over $k$.Therefore the extension $k [X]/k$ is not algebraic rather it is transcendental.

But I am not completely convinced with my argument.Are there more intuitive way to view this fact? If such things do exist please let me know somebody. Then it will be really helpful for me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What you wrote is the precise reason why that extension is not algebraic: it contains elements which are not algebraic over k. What more could you possibly want?!

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez do you say that  I am correct in my reasoning?

Comment: Why would it not be correct? An extension of k is algebraic if every element is algebraic over k: you showed that X is an elementary of k(X) that is not a root of a polynomial with coefficients in k, so that it is not algebraic.

Comment: Sorry @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez for creating annoyance to you.

Comment: You have not done any such thing! I am just saying that if some part of your argument makes you doubt you should really be more explicit about what it is.

Comment: That annoyance would be the possible reason for a downvote.

Comment: You are assuming that it was me who downvoted, and **that** is somewhat silly.

Comment: Oh!sorry.I misjudged you before reading your comment above. Excuse me please.